# Why I get an error as missing $, or missing {, or undefined environment, when I want to align the equations while using \mathbb?

Tags: equations, errors, align, split, mathbb

```
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbb{E}[X_t] & =\mathbb{E}[\alpha \circ X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t] \\ 
    &=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}{Y_j + \epsilon_t}] \\
    &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\mathbb{E}[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}Y_j|X_{t-1}=n] \mathbb{P}[X_{t-1}=n]} +\mu_{\epsilon}\\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\mathbb{E}[Y_j] \mathbb{P}[X_{t-1}=n]}}} +\mu_{\epsilon}
    \end{split}
  
    \end{equation*}

    \\ We can use recursion to express it in terms of $X_0$:
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    \mathbb{E}[X_t] & =\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}] + \mu_{\epsilon} \\
    &= \alpha [\alpha  \mathbb{E}[X_{t-2}+ \mu_{\epsilon}]+ \mu_{\epsilon}\\
    &=\alpha^2  \mathbb{E}[X_{t-2}]+ \alpha \mu_{\epsilon}+\mu_{\epsilon} \\
    &=....\\
    &=\alpha^t\mathbb{E}[X_0]+\alpha^{t-1}\mu_{\epsilon}+...+\alpha\mu_{\epsilon}+\mu_{\epsilon}\\
    &=\alpha^t\mathbb{E}[X_0]+\mu_{\epsilon}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\alpha^j}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
    
    \begin{equation*}   
\begin{split}
    Var[X_t] & = Var[\alpha \circ X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t]                                                                           \\
             & = Var[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}Y_j]+Var[\epsilon_t]                                                                   \\
             & =\mathbb{E}[{[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}Y_j}]^2]-{\mathbb{E}\big[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}Y_j]}\big]^2+ \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \\
             & =\mathbb{E}[{[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}Y_j}]^2]-\alpha^2\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}]^2+\sigma_{\epsilon}^2
             \end{split}
             \end{equation*}
             \\
             
             \begin{equation*}  
             \begin{split}
             \mathbb{E}[{[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}Y_j}]^2] & =\mathbb{E}[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}{Y_j}^2 + \sum_{i\neq j}^{X_{t-1}}Y_iY_j]\\
             & =\mathbb{E}[\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-1}}{Y_j}^2]+\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\neq j}^{X_{t-1}}Y_iY_j] 
              
         
             \end{split}
             \end{equation*}
```

Comment: Blank lines are not allowed in math mode, see the blank line before end equation

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Why is the upper limit of summation frequently given by `X_{t-1}`; why not `\infty`?

Comment: It is a random sum, so X_{t-1}  is a random variable.

Comment: This is a duplicate, here is one such question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375015/3929